# Accessing the special function registers on MAXIM MAX32670 MCU

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I already have experience in developing software on Renesas's MCUs for approximately 5 years but I'm new to developing on MAXIM's MAX32670 MCU including other ARM architecture MCUs.

This time, the MAX32670 become candidacy on the next MCU for using in next our products and I need to evaluate it.

So, I'm trying to write a program that communicates a PC using the serial communication module embedded in this MCU, for understanding how to use this MCU.

I think that the special function register needs to be accessed to configure the device-specific hardware module (such as the UART) embedded on MCU.

In the user's guide for the MAX32670, there is the description that the special function registers can be accessed by the following style of description but the compiler shows an error message ( not defined ) and failed the build process.

`UART0_CLKDIV.clkdiv = 417    // Set baud rate to 9,600bps`

Some header files are included at the head of my source code. These were automatically added by the Eclipse.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "mxc_device.h"
#include "mxc_sys.h"
#include "nvic_table.h"
#include "gpio.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "tmr.h"
#include "led.h"
```

I have installed MAXIM Micros SDK before starting this project. It contains Eclipse and other GNU tools for developing on MAX32670.

Does anyone know the correct way for accessing the special function registers?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! -- The manufacturer surely provides a lot of tutorial material. You read it, didn't you? And you followed some quick start guide, didn't you? -- Anyway, the question you asked can be answered by "Yes, many people know how to access SFR." You already show one way in your code excerpt. -- Please [edit] your question, providing a [example] with emphasis on _complete_, the commands to compile and link, commonly shown in Eclipse, and the exact error message.

Comment: @thebusybee In all fairness, literally every single silicon vendor out there has a very long tradition giving out horrible examples, horrible tutorials, horrible libraries, horrible app notes and horrible Eclipse hellspawn IDEs.  So anything they hand you to get you started should be regarded with massive scepticism.

Comment: Try to mark `UART0_CLKDIV` then hit F3. Where does it take you, if anywhere? Is the header file you end up in included in your project, directly or indirectly? Getting Eclipse projects to link is always a major pain - I'd strongly recommend to use another IDE, though I haven't used the one by Maxim specifically.

Comment: Thank you everyone, and sorry for my late response.

I tried press F3 with marked the UART0_CLKDIV but nothing occurred.
So I think that my project is lacking some header files or descriptions is wrong.

Maybe, in somewhere, there are header file needs to be used for accessing the SFR but I have not found yet.

I will keep searching the header file a little more.
If no anywhere the header file, I will try to make it.
And also, I have asked the MAXIM but I do not have a response yet.
 
Thank you.